# Split address column by the first number that appears

Tags: python

I have a dataset for which I'm trying to fix the address situation. The data for the Address column comes with the name of the person who ordered by default, so the column look something like this:

```
**Address**
John Snow 333 East Road 123 MA United States
Mary Scott 123 South Road 321 MA United States
```

What I need is a way to split the column when the first number appears, so that I end up with a "Name" column and a "New Address" column. It is important to keep everything after the first number and not to split at every number that appears in the Address column.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: For clarification splitting at the first number will give John Snow + 333 East Road 123 MA United States. Don't you want two splits?

Comment: Is this `pandas`? You talk a lot about columns, but then only show text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `df`:

```
                                          address
0    John Snow 333 East Road 123 MA United States
1  Mary Scott 123 South Road 321 MA United States
```

Doing:

```
df[['name', 'new_address']] = df.address.str.extract('(.+?)\s(\d+.+)')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                          address        name                          new_address
0    John Snow 333 East Road 123 MA United States   John Snow   333 East Road 123 MA United States
1  Mary Scott 123 South Road 321 MA United States  Mary Scott  123 South Road 321 MA United States
```

[Regexr Explanation](https://regexr.com/6vt5m)

Answer (score 0):

Using regex

```py
text = John Snow 333 East Road 123 MA United States
res = re.search("(\d+)", s)
# -> <re.Match object; span=(10, 13), match='333'>
start, end = s.span()
before = text[:start].strip() # away spaces which might or might not be there
after = text[end:].strip()
print(before, "|", after)
# btw. here you can get the number by res[0]
# -> John Snow | East Road 123 MA United States
```

But that seams not like a logical and usefull split?

Some improvement would be

```py
res = re.match("^(.+?)(\d+)(.+)(\d+)(.+)", text)
print(res.groups())
#-> ('John Snow ', '333', ' East Road ', '123', ' MA United States')
```

Adjust the groups to your liking. But be aware that this will produce problems if more than 2 number blocks occure!